# Using NGINX release, not building from source, how to use server_tokens?

Tags: nginx

I'm using the stable release of NGINX 1.22.0 without building from source, so I do not have access to the more_headers module. According to:

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_tokens

I should be able to use the server_tokens directive. I don't need the "String" parameter so the "commercial release" part shouldn't be relevant.

I tried just server_tokens off in /etc/nginx/conf.d/mydomain.conf, not inside a server or location block.

I get the error:

```
nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "server_tokens" directive
```

I also tried

```
server_tokens off ""
```

with the same error

What is the proper syntax?

Comment: `server_tokens off;`

Comment: Thank you Artem that is all it was. Missing the ';'